# set of group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G,H$ be groups and let $Hom (G,H)$ be the set of group homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$. Prove that $Hom (G,H)$ is a group. Find the order of $Hom (\mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z})$ in terms of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: ...please...? ...some self effort there...?

Comment: What would you guess as being a 'natural' way to 'put two homomorphisms $G\rightarrow H$ together'?

Comment: yeah...put in some effort. its not difficult

Comment: I don't think you'll find that $\operatorname{Hom}(G,H)$ is a group unless $H$ is abelian. Take $G = H$ and $1 \in \operatorname{Hom}(G,H)$. What is the product of $1$ and $1$ in the group on $\operatorname{Hom}(G,H)$?

Comment: Questions posted here should come with citations of the source, and indication of having put more effort into the question than just copy-pasting it in. Also, some idea of what you know about the topic would be helpful to anyone trying to compose an answer.

Comment: Here is what I get: I think the group operation is $(f+g)(x)= f(x) + g(x)$? And the identity is $Id: G \rightarrow H$ which sends everything to $e_H$? And the inverse of $f$ is $(-f)(x)= -f(x) $? But then I still don't have any clue on the order of $Hom (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$...

Comment: @Sherly good, that is correct (as long as $H$ is commutative, otherwise $f+g$ is usually not a homomorphism). You might think about $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},H)$ for arbitrary $H$. If $1+m\mathbb{Z}$ is sent to $h$, where is $2+m\mathbb{Z}$ sent?